# RefineryCMS image uploading error,  ImageMagick CentOS 5.5 

Tags: imagemagick, centos, image-uploading, refinerycms

I installed RefineryCMS on my server(CentOs 5.5) and everything works fine except uploading images. It will show an error like:

```
NoMethodError in Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create

   undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

I installed ImageMagick by typing:

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick
```

I searched online and it seems ImageMagick installed by yum is too old (Version 6.2.x)
Then I removed it, successfully installed ImageMagick v6.7.7 from source code.
Now when I try to upload an image, refinery shows:

```
Dragonfly::Shell::CommandFailed in Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create

   Command failed (identify '/tmp/RackMultipart20120628-29239-70xr45') with exit status 127
```

However, if I run that command "identify '/tmp/RackMultipart20120628-29239-70xr45'" in the command line, it will show the result without any error. It seems that Dragonfly can not pick up my installation of the lastest version of ImageMagick. Could any one tell me how to configure it ?  Or should I upgrade my centOS ?(I wish not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have struggled with this issue for more than one week.
I also asked this question in Github and finally got the solution there.
see: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/issues/1781#issuecomment-6823858

Since this problem is caused by that Dragonfly can not find imagemagick. 
You can try add the following code to config/application.rb

```
initializer 'override-image-magick-paths', :after => 'attach-refinery-images-with-      dragonfly' do
  app=Dragonfly[:refinery_images]
  app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
  app.configure do |c|
    c.convert_command = "/usr/local/bin/convert"          # defaults to "convert"
    c.identify_command = "/usr/local/bin/identify"        # defaults to "identify"
  end
end
```

Modify the path according to your imagemagick installation. 
You can use which command to find the path. e.g. which convert

However, this still doesn't work for me. 
And finally, [toymachiner62](https://github.com/toymachiner62) find a solution which is simple and works perfect.

That is to use symbolic link:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert convert             
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/identify identify
```

modify the /usr/local/bin/convert paths to you installation as well.
This looks like my /usr/local/bin path is not in my $PATH, but actually it is.
Dragonfly just seems can not find it anyway.